# Magento 2 - How to format cart item price?

Tags: magento2, cart, price, totals, format

In magento 2, I don't know how to format cart item price.

***I have a price format like this : £1,522.58 and I want this format £1522,58***

I succeed to change the format of the total cart price by overriding

```
 getPriceFormat() method in Magento\Framework\Locale\Format.php file.
```

But it doesn't work for cart item total.

Do you know how to make this change ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. To format the price you can put below code into your block file.

   ```
   public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $pricingHelper)
   {
       $this->pricingHelper = $pricingHelper;
   }

   public function getCustomFormatedPrice($myprice)
   {
       return $this->pricingHelper->currency($myprice,true,false); 
   }
   ```
2. Now you can call it from your phtml file like this one.

   ```
   echo $block->getCustomFormatedPrice($myprice);
   ```